# How to implement native 'Sign In with Apple' flow

Tags: ios

I’ve got a question about implementing Sign In With Apple. I am newbie in Apple development so the question might be trivial.

My app consists of two parts - backend part written in Go and iOS/Android/browser clients. So all user management obviously happens at the backend side. Users can register and sign in by email etc. Clients just send login/email and password to backend, nothing unusual.

Some time ago I decided to implement Apple Sign In as an option to users who have Apple ID to register/login. I implemented it with WebView in Android following this instruction https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple for browsers, Android and iOS < 13.0 and it works really well. After successful login a call from Apple to backend redirect URI happens and then backend handles user data and makes calls to clients to refresh page etc.

But then I made native implementation of Sign In With Apple in iOS >= 13.0. I followed this instruction https://developerinsider.co/ios-13-how-to-integrate-sign-in-with-apple-in-your-application/ to implement it and authentication happens at Apple side well but then it just returns user data to Swift and that’s all.  I can’t figure out how to tell backend that login is done. Can anybody tell me how to include backend in the flow? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single Sign ON (SSO) in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813517/single-sign-on-sso-in-ios-7)

Comment: @adripanico Duplicate , that too iOS7. Dude, check before comment

Comment: You need to provide the JWT and the `identityToken` to your server. Your server then validates this identity token with Apple's service https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens and the user is now logged in.

Comment: @Paulw11 I succeed with it. All we need is to start a usual SSO process but not from the beginning (send cliend_id, redirect_uri and state) but with the request which usually goes second (when sending the code and client_secret etc), and the code we got along with identityToken is the code we need to send there. A lot of thanks to you!